# How can i resolve Paypal::Exception::APIError Exception: PayPal API Error: 'Invalid Token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I'm using the paypal-express gem in my ruby on rails project. i am trying to implement Paypal recurring payment.

i am able to do the expresscheckout successfully, but i am facing above invalid token error for recurring payment. I am doing everything fine as described in paypal-express gem wiki. couldnt figure out what is wrong with this.

```
def paypal_checkout
    Paypal.sandbox! if Rails.env.development?
    request = Paypal::Express::Request.new(
      :username   => "USERNAME",
      :password   => "PASSWORD",
      :signature  => "SIGNATURE"
    )
    payment_request = Paypal::Payment::Request.new(
      :currency_code => :USD,
      :billing_type  => :RecurringPayments,
      :billing_agreement_description => "Recurring"
    )
    response = request.setup(
      payment_request,
      root_url,
      root_url
    )
    uri = response.redirect_uri
    token = CGI.parse(uri)['token'].join #here I successfully get the response token

    profile = Paypal::Payment::Recurring.new(
      :start_date => Date.today,
      :description => "Recurring",
      :billing => {
        :period        => :Week,
        :frequency     => "1",
        :amount        => "15",
        :currency_code => :USD
      }
    )
    response = request.subscribe!(token, profile) # here i face the 'invalid token error'

  end
```

payment_request_response =

```
#<Paypal::Payment::Request:0x007fa3ca7b3a20 @amount=#<Paypal::Payment::Common::Amount:0x007fa3ca7b39d0 @total=0, @item=0, @fee=0, @handing=0, @insurance=0, @ship_disc=0, @shipping=0, @tax=0, @gross=0, @net=0>, @items=[], @custom_fields={}, @action=nil, @currency_code=:USD, @description=nil, @notify_url=nil, @billing_type=:RecurringPayments, @billing_agreement_description="Recurring billing description", @billing_agreement_id=nil, @request_id=nil, @seller_id=nil, @invoice_number=nil, @custom=nil>
```

Profile response =

`#<Paypal::Payment::Recurring:0x007fd3f0fd78e0 @start_date=Mon, 01 Sep 2014, @description="Recurring billing description", @identifier=nil, @status=nil, @name=nil, @reference=nil, @max_fails=0, @auto_bill=nil, @aggregate_amount=0, @aggregate_optional_amount=0, @final_payment_date=nil, @billing=#<Paypal::Payment::Recurring::Billing:0x007fd3f0fd5248 @amount=#<Paypal::Payment::Common::Amount:0x007fd3f0fd5158 @total=15, @item=0, @fee=0, @handing=0, @insurance=0, @ship_disc=0, @shipping=0, @tax=0, @gross=0, @net=0>, @period=:Month, @frequency=1, @paid=0, @currency_code=:USD, @total_cycles=0>>`

Comment: i have created paypal sandbox testing account and here i am using sellers api credentials

Comment: Can you paste the complete response here from PayPal?